# QueryStore plan forcing errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-store

We have a weekly stored procedure that ocassionaly picks up wrong execution plan that causes much longer execution times.

I've tried to force correct execution plan but still every few weeks the execution plan forcing fails with following error:

> Query processor could not produce query plan because USE PLAN hint
> contains plan that could not be verified to be legal for query. Remove
> or replace USE PLAN hint. For best likelihood of successful plan
> forcing, verify that the plan provided in the USE PLAN hint is one
> generated automatically by SQL Server for the same query.

Sometimes even after such error the good execution plan is created and used (see following screenshot)
[image: 3 months plan history]

The good execution plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1NIXXohp

Slow execution plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy3fmmjnp

Query itself is visible in the plans (tried to insert it here but it gets strange formating).

When I implemented the index suggested by the second plan:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
> 'MEX.Agreement_Transaction_Table' with unique index
> 'IX_AgrTblIncludes'. The duplicate key value is (202304, 1, 0,
> 0xa0be430067091800).

What could be the reason of picking wrong plan/plan forcing failures?

Answer (score 1):

> When I implemented the index suggested by the second plan:

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'MEX.Agreement_Transaction_Table' with unique index 'IX_AgrTblIncludes'. The duplicate key value is (202304, 1, 0, 0xa0be430067091800
```

First of all it is NOT the index suggested in the second plan, SQL Server just cannot know if your columns gives a `unique` combination so any suggested index is NOT `unique`,
and what you've created IS `unique`.
The suggested index was

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [MEX].[Agreement_Transaction_Table] ([Accounting_Week_Num],[Committed_Bln],[Deleted_Flag])
INCLUDE ([FT_L_Agreement_Id],[FT_L_Accounting_Week_Id],[FT_L_Agreement_Transaction_Id],[FT_L_Agreement_Transaction_Type_Id],[Agreement_Transaction_Id],[Agreement_Transaction_Db_Id],[Agency_Id],[Agreement_Db_Id],[Agreement_Transaction_Type_Code],[Agreement_Id],[Company_Code],[Creation_Date],[Product_Version_Db_Id],[Product_Version_Id],[Value],[Write_Off_Reason_Code],[Effective_Accounting_Week_Num],[Transaction_Date],[Committed_Date])
```

and it has 3 key columns and it is not `unique`,
the index giving you the error is `unique` and has at least 4 columns (the values are truncated in the error output)

The reason why these two plans are different is the parameter value used for compilation, for earlier date (202313) you've got better plan as there is statistics for this value, and for 202333 it estimates just one row that is wrong.

Your main problem here is the wrong structure of Agreement_Transaction_Table,
it's a partitioned heap that seems to have last partition limit value 202052, so it's not maintained anymore, that is why the estimations are wrong, you should add missing partitions to correct it.

In my opinion it should be clustered index on Accounting_Week_Num, but I don't know the reasons why do you choose to have a heap

Comment: Recommended index from slow plan was successfully created as non-unique for a table with over 750 million rows.
We've alsa tried the index without the include part and to add 2 key columns to it (
table is not a heap).
Every time we've encountered erratic issues with new inserts (edited the question to include whole error message). Perhaps this could be better to ask in another question why inserts fail.  
I got your point that the parameter values are different and thats why we use plan force option from the query store, but this occasionaly also does not work.

Comment: @AndrzejBłoch "Recommended index from slow plan was successfully created as **non-unique**" but the error you've posted says "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'MEX.Agreement_Transaction_Table' with **unique** index 'IX_AgrTblIncludes'. The duplicate key value is..." if this index already existed why do you say "When I implemented the index suggested by the second plan"?

Comment: @AndrzejBłoch "table is not a heap" your table Agreement_Transaction_Table has no clustered index, it IS a heap and even the plan says: **Table** scan (not Index scan), and it makes **RID** lookup

Comment: @AndrzejBłoch I suggest you to script your IX_AgrTblIncludes so that you can see its definition. It is unique and if it's not your requirement you can re-create it as non unique.

Comment: IX_AgrTblIncludes is exactly the one that is in the missing index recommendation for the slow plan.

We've tried 3 versions of it (1 - as it is in the missing index recommendation, 2 with 2 additional columns that forms PK of the table, 3 the same as 1 but without the included part)

With each of the indexes we've encountered issues with the inserts (similar to the ones that are in the question).

That's why we've dropped it and try to force working plan.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked when stats are updated and tried updating them prior to the insert query?

I notice you are filtering on "week_num", you could be experiencing the ascending key problem.